# How to apply Form validation for React Material-UI TextField and Select?

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

I'm trying to add validation to TextField and Select before going to handleNext(). Here is the code (2 components):

```
class Quote extends React.Component {
state = {
    activeStep: 0,
    zipCode: '',
    destination: '',
    sedanPrice: '',
    suvPrice: '',
    labelWidth: 0,
};

getStepContent = (step) => {
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return (
                <div>
                    <QuoteForm
                        {...this.state}
                        {...this.state.value}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        case 1:
            return (
                <div>
                    <QuotePrice 
                        {...this.state}
                        {...this.state.value}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown step');
    }
}

handleNext = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1,
    }));
    switch(this.state.activeStep){
        case 0: 
            // Creates an API call for sedan pricing
            API.getPrice(this.state.zipCode, "sedan" + this.state.destination).then(res => {
                let price = res.data;
                let key = Object.keys(price);
                console.log("Sedan price is $" + price[key]);
                this.setState({sedanPrice: price[key]});
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

            // Creates an API call for SUV pricing
            API.getPrice(this.state.zipCode, "suv" + this.state.destination).then(res => {
                let price = res.data;
                let key = Object.keys(price);
                console.log("SUV price is $" + price[key])
                this.setState({suvPrice: price[key]});
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        break
        case 1:
            console.log('forward to booking page');
            window.location.href = '/booking';
        break
        default: 
            console.log('over');
    }
};

handleBack = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        activeStep: state.activeStep - 1,
        sedanPrice: '',
        suvPrice: '',
        destination: '',
        zipCode: '',
    }));
};

handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
        activeStep: 0,
    });
};

handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value,
    });
};

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { activeStep } = this.state;
    const steps = ['Pick Up Address', 'Select Your Vehicle'];

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <main className={classes.layout}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <React.Fragment>
                        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                    Thank you for your interest!
                                </Typography>
                            </React.Fragment>
                            ) : (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {this.getStepContent(activeStep)}
                                <div className={classes.buttons}>
                                    {activeStep !== 0 && (
                                        <Button onClick={this.handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                                            Back
                                        </Button>
                                    )}
                                    <Button
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="primary"
                                        onClick={this.handleNext}
                                        className={classes.button}
                                    >
                                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Book Now' : 'Next'}
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            </React.Fragment>
                            )}
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Paper>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

QuoteForm.js

```
export class QuoteForm extends React.Component {

state = {
    zipCode: this.props.zipCode,
    destination: this.props.destination,
}

render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Typography variant="h5" align="center">
                Enter your zip code for a quick quote
            </Typography>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid className={classes.TextField} item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <TextField
                        required
                        id="zip"
                        name="zipCode"
                        label="Zip / Postal code"
                        fullWidth
                        autoComplete="billing postal-code"
                        value={this.props.zipCode}
                        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <FormControl xs={12} sm={6} className={classes.formControl}>
                    <Select
                        required
                        value={this.props.destination}
                        onChange={this.props.handleChange}
                        input={<Input name="destination" />}
                        displayEmpty
                        name="destination"
                        className={classes.selectEmpty}
                    >
                        <MenuItem value="">
                            <em>Select Your Airport *</em>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem name="SAN" value={"SAN"}>San Diego International Airport</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem name="LAX" value={"LAX"}>Los Angeles International Airport</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

I tried 2 different ways. First, using Button disabled and writing a function to handle the validation and set disabled to false. Second, using npm package to handle validation. Both failed since I'm new to this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you not using https://react-hook-form.com/ and https://github.com/jquense/yup it will be great and easy with lots of features.

Comment: Because React-Hook-Form doesn't work with classes, that's why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following:

- maintain a boolean state say `error` and `errorMessage`
- in handleNext, validate he input values and set error to false and set a message to the error.
- For material ui Textfield, use `error` and `helperText` [props](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) to set/display errors nicely beside your fields
- For material ui Select, use `FormControl` `error` prop and provide `label` to `Select` in order to set/display errors nicely beside your fields
- don't let the user go to next form until error is fixed.
- pass `error` and `errorMessage` to `QuoteForm` component.

[Working copy of your code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-validation-issue-fix-ev81h?file=/src/Quote.js) in the codesandbox

**state**

```js
state = {
    activeStep: 0,
    zipCode: "",
    destination: "",
    sedanPrice: "",
    suvPrice: "",
    labelWidth: 0,
    error: false, //<---- here
    errorMessage: {} //<-----here
  };
```

**handleNext**

```js
handleNext = () => {
    let isError = false;
    if (this.state.zipCode.length < 2) {
      isError = true;
      this.setState({
        error: true,
        errorMessage: { zipCode: "enter correct zipcode" }
      });
    } 
    if (this.state.destination === '') {
      isError = true;
      this.setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        error: true,
        errorMessage: { ...prev.errorMessage, destination: "enter correct destination" }
      }))
    }  if(!isError){
      //add else if for validating other fields (if any)
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1,
        error: false,
        errorMessage: {}
      }));
    }
  ...
```

**Mui Textfield**

```js
          <TextField
              error={!!this.props.errorMessage.zipCode}
              required
              id="zip"
              name="zipCode"
              label="Zip / Postal code"
              fullWidth
              autoComplete="billing postal-code"
              value={this.props.zipCode}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              helperText={
                this.props.errorMessage.zipCode &&
                this.props.errorMessage.zipCode
              }
            />
```

**Mui Select** use

```js
<FormControl xs={12} sm={6} error={this.props.error}>
            <Select
              error={!!this.props.errorMessage.destination}
              label="enter cor dest"
              required
              value={this.props.destination}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
              input={<Input name="destination" />}
              displayEmpty
              name="destination"
            >
              <MenuItem value="">
                <em>Select Your Airport *</em>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem name="SAN" value={"SAN"}>
                San Diego International Airport
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem name="LAX" value={"LAX"}>
                Los Angeles International Airport
              </MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText>
              {this.props.errorMessage.destination}
            </FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried something similar but with the handleChange function instead of handleNext(). It didn't work. This works great for the zip code validation. Should I add if/else for Select form just under the if/else you added in handleNext for the zipCode?

Comment: yes, you can add multiple `if`s to do validation ... i have updated the answer to cover select as well as the codesandbox is updated(same link) ... when validation becomes vast, then you can consider to use libraries such as `yup`..

Comment: Thanks. I see what you did. It works as is. Great work. I changed the if statement for zipCode to be in range to cover the ones in MySQL database (around 120 in total). The only problem is some of the zipCodes in that range are out of the service area and there is no price for them in the database. From experienced look at this, is it better to do additional API call that would check if the zipCode is in the database and display these error messages or list the zipcodes in an array in code and loop thru it?